# When I should dispatch async action in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In different redux guides I saw different approaches of dispatching api actions.
For example in redux-reddit app async action is dispatching in `componentDidMount` function:

```
class AsyncApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleRefreshClick = this.handleRefreshClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
  }
  ...
```

In real world example async action is dispatching in `componentWillMount` function:

```
function loadData(props) {
  const { login } = props
  props.loadUser(login, [ 'name' ])
  props.loadStarred(login)
}

class UserPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.renderRepo = this.renderRepo.bind(this)
    this.handleLoadMoreClick = this.handleLoadMoreClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    loadData(this.props)
  }
```

So, what correct way for dispatching async actions? Or it doesn't matter? Also, as I know, in es6 classes `componentWillMount` function is replaced by constructor..

Comment: It depends on your situation, both are Ok. The difference between `componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount` are: 1, `componentDidMount` runs after `componentWillMount`; 2, `componentDidMount` only runs on the client side. see [component lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building isomorphic apps (both client and server rendering), you tend to use `componentDidMount` because you only want to issue the ajax call from the client and `componentDidMount` only runs on the client.